# display dialog box and redirect to other URL in Laravel 5.5 PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel PHP 5.5 to develop a security access system. Can anyone guide me on how to display a dialog box and user click ok it will redirect to another page after value inserted into DB?

Comment: Hi andy, welcome to Stack Overflow. Take a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topic can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This is not really a question that belongs to Stack Overflow. SO is meant for exact reproducible problems with verifiable answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap modal or Jquery Dialogue box for opening a dialog

Make sure are u inserting the data using the Ajax then on success method you can 
use window.location or some redirect logic whatever you want
You can also use echo function in which  you can use SCRIPT tag and redirect with window.location

link here..
     `http://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/`
For the dialogbox